# Firebase trigger function ignored due to missing "firebaseauth.googleapis.com emulator"

Tags: firebase, triggers, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase function `createUser` that is triggered by `auth.user().onCreate`.
Whenever I serve functions locally, it is ignored.
I get the same output when I run `firebase serve`, `firebase serve -only functions,firestore`, `firebase emulators:start`, or `firebase emulators:start --only functions,firestore`:

```
⚠  functions: Your GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable points to /home/david/Sync/alikely/key.json. Non-emulated services will access production using these credentials. Be careful!
✔  functions[createItem]: http function initialized (http://localhost:5000/alikely-ce1d5/us-central1/createItem).
i  functions[createUser]: function ignored because the firebaseauth.googleapis.com emulator does not exist or is not running.
```

As shown above, I have attempted to follow the instructions to setup admin credentials here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator.

I have initialized functions and firestore with `firebase init`, and my project directory contains a `firestore.rules`, `firestore.indexes.json`, and a `firebase.json`. Are the contents of one of these files to blame?

How can I locally emulate all of my functions for full local development? How can I enable the "firebaseauth.googleapis.com emulator"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you linked says:

> The Firebase CLI includes a Cloud Functions emulator which can emulate
>   the following function types:
>
> - HTTPS functions
> - Callable functions
> - Cloud Firestore functions

Auth functions are currently not supported, just the three types mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mr Doug. What are callable functions exactly? I've been trying to run my firebase database cloud function but I am not getting any report in my callback function that takes in the `snapshot` and the `context`.

Are the database functions part of the callable functions?